# T/F $A_3$ is a commutative group

Tags: group-theory

I believe it is false, but because it doesn't even form a group. And set of permutations which consist of odd number of transpositions would not form a group I think. Since odd+odd= even. Am I correct?

Comment: $A_3$ is the set of even permutations in $S_3$ It is a subgroup of index $2$ in $S_3$, hence has $3$ elements. What can you say about a group with $3$ elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $A_n$ *always* forms a subgroup of $S_n$, since the product of even permutations is again even, and the identity permutation is even. From a more advanced perspective, define $\operatorname{sgn}:S_n \rightarrow C_2$, which sends even permutations to 0 and odd permutations to 1 ($C_2$ is the cyclic group with 2 elements, isomorphic to $\{0,1\}$ with addition modulo 2). Then, $A_n$ is precisely the kernel of $\operatorname{sgn}$, and every kernel is a subgroup (even a normal subgroup). This also means that $|A_n| = \frac{|S_n|}{2}=\frac{n!}{2}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Since $|A_3| = \frac{3!}{2} = \frac{6}{2} = 3$, we know that $A_3$ has three elements. Now, any group with prime order is in fact cyclic; in particular, it is commutative. Thus $A_3 \cong C_3$.

Explicitly, $A_3 = \{(), (123), (132)\}$. Any nontrivial permutation generates the whole $A_3$, for example:

$$(123)^0 = ()$$
$$(123)^1 = (123)$$
$$(123)^2 = (132)$$